# sh: 0: Can't open

Tags: sh

I am trying to run this command

```
sh bbmap/bbduk.sh in1=fastq/Brca1Reads_ALL.1.fastq out1=fastq/Brca1Reads_ALL.1.TRIMMED.fastq ref=bbmap/resources/adapters.fa
```

On terminal, but I keep getting:

```
sh: 0: Can't open bbmap/bbduk.sh
```

I can't open bbduk.sh directly with terminal either. I have tried chmod, given permissions from the main folder but nothing seems to work.

I tried using bash but it gives `no such file or directory`.
Ran `namei -l bbmap/bbduk.sh` and it gives:

```
f: bbmap/bbduk.sh
drwxrwxr-x rizwan rizwan bbmap
-rwxrwxr-x rizwan rizwan bbduk.sh
```

The first few lines after cat are:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage(){
echo "
Written by Brian Bushnell
Last modified March 24, 2020

Description:  Compares reads to the kmers in a reference dataset, optionally 
allowing an edit distance. Splits the reads into two outputs - those that 
match the reference, and those that don't. Can also trim (remove) the matching 
parts of the reads rather than binning the reads.
Please read bbmap/docs/guides/BBDukGuide.txt for more information.

Usage:  bbduk.sh in=<input file> out=<output file> ref=<contaminant files>

Input may be stdin or a fasta or fastq file, compressed or uncompressed.
If you pipe via stdin/stdout, please include the file type; e.g. for gzipped 
fasta input, set in=stdin.fa.gz

Input parameters:
in=<file>           Main input. in=stdin.fq will pipe from stdin.
in2=<file>          Input for 2nd read of pairs in a different file.
ref=<file,file>     Comma-delimited list of reference files.
                    In addition to filenames, you may also use the keywords:
                    adapters, artifacts, phix, lambda, pjet, mtst, kapa
literal=<seq,seq>   Comma-delimited list of literal reference sequences.
touppercase=f       (tuc) Change all bases upper-case.
interleaved=auto    (int) t/f overrides interleaved autodetection.
qin=auto            Input quality offset: 33 (Sanger), 64, or auto.
reads=-1            If positive, quit after processing X reads or pairs.
copyundefined=f     (cu) Process non-AGCT IUPAC reference bases by making all
                    possible unambiguous copies.  Intended for short motifs
                    or adapter barcodes, as time/memory use is exponential.
samplerate=1        Set lower to only process a fraction of input reads.
samref=<file>       Optional reference fasta for processing sam files.
```

The output of strace sh bbmap/bbduk.sh is:

```
execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "bbmap/bbduk.sh"], 0x7fff99305048 /* 61 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55ca4513d000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffebb69790) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=72928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 72928, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f8ae922a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0cBR\340\305\370\2609W\242\345)q\235A\1"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8ae9228000
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0cBR\340\305\370\2609W\242\345)q\235A\1"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f8ae9036000
mprotect(0x7f8ae905b000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f8ae905b000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f8ae905b000
mmap(0x7f8ae91d3000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19d000) = 0x7f8ae91d3000
mmap(0x7f8ae921e000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f8ae921e000
mmap(0x7f8ae9224000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8ae9224000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f8ae9229580) = 0
mprotect(0x7f8ae921e000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55ca4456a000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f8ae9269000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f8ae922a000, 72928)           = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getpid()                                = 11570
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x55ca4455fc30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f8ae907c210}, NULL, 8) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55ca4513d000
brk(0x55ca4515e000)                     = 0x55ca4515e000
getppid()                               = 11567
stat("/home/rizwan/fastq", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "bbmap/bbduk.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55ca4455fc30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f8ae907c210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f8ae907c210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f8ae907c210}, NULL, 8) = 0
read(10, "#!/bin/bash\n\nusage(){\necho \"\nWri"..., 8192) = 8192
read(10, "do kmer-based operations on read"..., 8192) = 8192
read(10, "                  at least this "..., 8192) = 3318
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11
close(1)                                = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/games/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/games/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/snap/bin/pushd", 0x7fffebb69420) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "bbmap/bbduk.sh: 321: ", 21bbmap/bbduk.sh: 321: )   = 21
write(2, "pushd: not found", 16pushd: not found)        = 16
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
dup2(11, 1)                             = 1
close(11)                               = 0
write(2, "bbmap/bbduk.sh: 322: ", 21bbmap/bbduk.sh: 322: )   = 21
write(2, "Bad substitution", 16Bad substitution)        = 16
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

Comment: You must be able to open and see what is in bbduk.sh. Use cat bbduk.sh and add  the first few lines to your question. Do you get the same error message when you use bash instead of sh?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `namei -l bbmap/bbduk.sh`

Comment: Look at `bbmap/bbduk.sh` with `pathlld` from https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Please add the output of `strace sh bbmap/bbduk.sh` to the question.

Comment: I have added the output of strace sh bbmap/bbduk.sh